# How do I deploy a juju charm using juju-deployer from a private git repository?

Tags: juju, git

I have charms stored in a private Git repository. I am trying to use `juju-deployer` to deploy a charm directly from that Git repository.

Let's say the Git repo is `git@10.10.10.10:charms.git` and in that repository I have a charm located in the `trusty/rsyslog` directory. I want to be able to define my `juju-deployer` YAML file something like this:

```yaml
        "rsyslog":
      charm: rsyslog
#      branch: "git@10.10.10.10:charms.git/trusty/rsyslog@4f18be16d9f920ebb7f725998e7d2d08bbdd64fe"
      branch: "http://10.10.10.10/charms.git/trusty/rsyslog@4f18be16d9f920ebb7f725998e7d2d08bbdd64fe"
      num_units: 1
      to: 0
      options:
        messages_rotate: 30
        nova_logs: true
        syslog_rotate: 30
```

But I keep getting an error from juju-deployer (version 0.5.1.-3)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/juju-deployer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('juju-deployer==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'juju-deployer')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/cli.py", line 135, in main
    run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/cli.py", line 233, in run
    importer.Importer(env, deployment, options).run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/action/importer.py", line 294, in run
    self.get_charms()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/action/importer.py", line 146, in get_charms
    no_local_mods=self.options.no_local_mods)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/deployment.py", line 170, in fetch_charms
    for charm in self.get_charms():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/deployment.py", line 162, in get_charms
    yield Charm.from_service(k, self.repo_path, self.series, v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/charm.py", line 96, in from_service
    return cls(name, charm_path, branch, rev, build, store_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/charm.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.vcs = self.get_vcs()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deployer/charm.py", line 44, in get_vcs
    "Could not determine vcs backend for %s" % self.branch)
ValueError: Could not determine vcs backend for http://10.10.10.10/charms.git/trusty/rsyslog
```

If I try using the commented out line in the YAML file above, then it gives me a different error:

```
2015-09-15 08:10:08  Branching charm git @ precise/rsyslog
2015-09-15 08:10:08 Could not branch git to precise/rsyslog
 fatal: repository 'git' does not exist
2015-09-15 08:10:08 Deployment stopped. run time: 0.27
```

This error is strange because I don't have ANY mention of precise in my YAML file.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, that `http://10.10.10.10/charms.git/trusty/rsyslog@4f18be16d9f920ebb7f725998e7d2d08bbdd64fe` is a valid way to refer to a subdirectory inside a Git commit object in a repository accessible via HTTP.

Comment: I don't think juju-deployer has a handler for http, only for git and bzr. Try to run manually `git clone --depth 1 git@10.10.10.10:charms.git/trusty/rsyslog@4f18be16d9f920ebb7f725998e7d2d08bbdd64fe precise/rsyslog`

Comment: Right, I can't find any documentation about the formatting necessary to get juju-devployer to fetch charms from a git repo so I've been just messing around with the formatting.

I just tried this manually and it works (githq = my git repo IP):
`git clone --depth 1 git@githq:charms.git trusty/rsyslog`
When I add the "@4f18..." it complains.

Comment: This seems to be closer to what it is looking for: `branch: "githq:charms.git/trusty/rsyslog@4f18be16d9f920ebb7f725998e7d2d08bbdd64fe"
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For git, the `branch:` string should:

- begin with 'git', or
- contain 'github.com', or
- contain 'git.launchpad.net', or
- be a local path to a git repo

If the string contains an '@' symbol (optional), everything after the '@' will be treated as the revision to checkout after the clone.

Comment: So if my git repository is githq.company.com then I would use: `branch: githq.company.com:charms.git@4f18be16d9f920ebb7f725998e7d2d08bbdd64fe"` ?? This seems to work for me except that it asks for a password. I have the keys set up properly because I can do a git clone manually. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Also, do you NEED to put in an "@"? What if I just want it to tak the latest?

Comment: @user2402934 Updated the answer the make it clear that the '@' is optional.

Comment: @user2402934 juju-deployer just shells out to `git clone`, so I don't know why one would work and not the other. I assume the user is the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes - they should be the same user. I even turned off password authentication in the ssh config file `PasswordAuthentication no` and that made it fail immediately (without asking me for a password) so I think there may be a problem with using ssh keys from juju-deployer. I was able to work around the issue by just doing a git clone and then making the yaml file point to the local repo. I still would like to see a formatting description of the yaml file and all the possible options.